# How to restore a Ubuntu USB stick?

Tags: usb, macosx, macbook-pro

I downloaded the ubuntu installation .iso from the web and burnt that onto a USB stick with `Startup Disk Creator`.

And now this usb stick cannot be recognized by MAC and more.

How could I restore it, so that I can transfer some data from mac onto it?

Answer (score 1):

To make the drive usable again simply format it by going to gparted (you'll have to put in your root password)[image]

select the drive (upper right hand corner)

right click on the partion and unmount it

right click on it again to format it to fat32 (or any format macs will take)

click the checkmark and you're done.